# Combine 2 csv files with same no. of features Python

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have 2 files with many observations. I need to merge both of them vertically. For example:
Csv A contains the foll data on some people:

```
Sr.no  Name, Age , Sex, Weight, Height  
1.     A,    12,   M,   40,     4ft  
2.     B,    13,   F,   35,     3.9ft       
3.     C,    15,   F,   45,     4.2ft
```

Csv B contains :

```
1. D,20,M,55,5.3ft   
2. E,22,F,53,5.0ft
```

i want the output to look as:

```
1. A, 12, M, 40, 4ft  
2. B, 13, F, 35, 3.9ft   
3. C, 15, F, 45, 4.2ft   
4. D, 20, M, 55, 5.3ft   
5. E, 22, F, 53, 5.0ft
```

Tried `a.merge` but don't know how to get through with the parameters.
and yes, i forgot to mention the index. the merged csv should show observations as 1,2,3,4,5 . Csv A has indexing as 1,2,3 and Csv B as 1,2.  After merging ,resultant index is 1,2,3,4,5..

Comment: Why don't you append the two files? The result will still be a valid CSV file.

Comment: and what about the index? both start from 1. so i'd want the second indexing to continue with the index of Csv A

Comment: The index is not present in the file, right? So python should index it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand what's the difficulty? Open file A in append mode and write lines from B to it.

Comment: actually there is an indexing in the file that i'm dealing with. i forgot to mention it in the example above. just check, i've edited my question above.

Comment: You have five apparently independent observations. Indexing may be arbitrary. It will not alter the observed data.

Comment: check my question again. this is what i want to do. [i've edited it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it.. its quite simple though. all u need to do is
`FileC = FileA.append(FileB ,ignore_index = True)` .

The index automatically readjusts in proper fashion. The indexing starts with 0 though , but that isn't a problem as each observation will have its unique index number.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want:

```
A = open('A.csv','r')
B = open('B.csv','r')
out = open('out.csv','w')
i = 0
# writing A file
for line in A:
    if i==0: # This is to handle the headers line in csv A
        out.write(line)
    else:
        out.write("%s. %s" %(i,line[line.find('.')+1:]))
    i = i+1

# This is to handle where there is not end-of-line at the end of A.csv
if not line.endswith("\n"):
    out.write("\n")

# writing B file
for line in B:
    out.write("%s. %s" %(i,line[line.find('.')+1:]))
    i = i+1
A.close()
B.close()
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would say that ignoring index during merging and creating your own index (just by counting the lines) during the runtime when you read the files again could be faster.
Then, talking about `file.merge()`, check this article about `pandas` package [Merge, join, and concatenate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html). `Merge` is not the thing you were looking for. It can merge CSV files in the way how you could do it in database. You could bend it to fit your purpose but I think that the best way is just to use the following simple code.

I suggest (for Python 2.5 and up) to use `with` for opening files. ([Python's `with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)).

```
import shutil;

def merge():
    print '*** Merging started ***';
    # opening all the files using with
    with open('fileA.csv','r') as fileA, open('fileB.csv','r') as fileB, open('fileOutput.csv','w') as output:
        # if all the files start by index no. 1, then you don't need to copy line by line the whole file and you can just use a copy of whole file
        # you just need to count the number of lines in order to know which number to use for fileB
        lines_counter = 0;
        for line in fileA:
            lines_counter += 1;

        # only copy the file fileA in fileOutput
        shutil.copyfile('fileA.csv','fileOutput.csv');

        # if the last line of fileA was not ended by end of line, append it
        if not line.endswith('\n'):
            output.write('\n');

        # copy all the lines of fileB and add the index which belongs to the line    
        for line in fileB:
            lines_counter += 1;
            line_without_index = line[line.find('.'):];
            output.write('{}{}'.format(str(lines_counter),line_without_index));

    print '*** Merging finished ***';

merge();
```

EDITED:

When `shutil` doesn't work you can still just remove

```
shutil.copyfile('fileA.csv','fileOutput.csv');
```

and add one line to the first for loop, so the first for-loop will look as follows:

```
for line in fileA:
    lines_counter += 1;
    output.write(line);
```

It should work the same way. There could be only really slight difference in performance. But I guess it is not a big deal.

Comment: hi, thanx for ur code, but the shutil module isnt callable. how do i install it? (or import it)?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c207988ad13a> in <module>()
     22         lines_counter += 1;
     23         line_without_index = line[line.find('.'):];
---> 24         output.write('{}{}'.format(str(lines_counter),line_without_index));
     25 
     26 print '*** Merging finished ***';

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

*** Merging started ***

Comment: Sorry, for that. You can import [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-shutil.html) by `import shutil` at the beginning of the code. I edited the code. I hope it is ok, now.

Comment: what version of Python do you use? When I test it, it seems ok and `shutil` should be a standard module in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import csv
from itertools import chain

with open('a.csv') as a, open('b.csv') as b, open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
    a = csv.reader(a)
    b = csv.reader(b)
    out = csv.writer(out)
    for i, row in enumerate(chain(a, b), 1):
        row[0] = i
        out.writerow(row)
```